# Trying to grap the input value and display, Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript

Is anyone else having trouble grabbing the input value using .value?

I usually do it like this, but doesn't seem to be working.

```
const getVal = document.getElementById('newtext').value;
const getBtn = document.getElementById('btn');

getBtn.addEventListener('click',displayNewText);

function displayNewText(){
    return document.getElementById('displaytext').innerHTML = getVal;
    console.log(getVal);
}


    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is my first note</h1>
    <input id="newtext" type="text" value=""><br>
    <button id="btn">Press Me</button>
    <h3 id="displaytext"></h3>
```

Comment: u mean `    return document.getElementById('displaytext').innerHTML == getVal;` , == instead of = , or remove return ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to get .value when the function is called and console.log will never show after the return statement, so to debug do it before.

```
const getVal = document.getElementById('newtext');
const getBtn = document.getElementById('btn');

getBtn.addEventListener('click',displayNewText);

function displayNewText(){
    console.log("im working yey")
    return document.getElementById('displaytext').innerHTML = getVal.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're getting value once your code gets excuted .. hence, value = ""

To solve this problem, you have to get value whenever the button is clicked

so, just move getVal inside the function

```js
const getBtn = document.getElementById('btn');

getBtn.addEventListener('click', displayNewText);

function displayNewText() {
  const getVal = document.getElementById('newtext').value;

  return document.getElementById('displaytext').innerHTML = getVal;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is my first note</h1>
<input id="newtext" type="text" value=""><br>
<button id="btn">Press Me</button>
<h3 id="displaytext"></h3>
```